# php не видит cookie "/" в другой папке.

Tags: php, cookie

Ситуция:
Папка "/", устанавливаем setcookie("a", 1, time()+3600*10101);
Заходим в папку "/test", читаем кук 'a'. Кука нет. Пошарился в интернете, пришел к выводу, что для каждой папки свои куки.
Как это исправить? Мне нужно из папки "/test" прочитать куки корневой директории.

Comment: он видит только куки в той ветке домена, в которую вы их установили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setcookie("a", "1",  time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/");
```

Т.е. укажите параметр "path".